# MongoDB search geospatial after searching by different index

Tags: performance, mongodb, geospatial

I have a big collection, with data arranged by lat-lng coordinates and time with respective indices (spherical geospatial and descending for the times).

There is roughly 10`000 points per time step and around 2000 time steps now, and I would like to find, say, values in the 5 points, closest to the given coordinates in some small time span.

The problem is that after number of records had hit 10 millions, the performance of the geospatial queries became unsettlingly unpredictable: what earlier always took only around 3 seconds to fetch and process, now can take all the way up to 45, which is unacceptable in my case.

From what I've read on the mongodb docs, it seems that if query requires to utilize geospatial index, by default it has priority over any other parts of the query, so in my case, search first goes through all 2000 of the time steps to find all the 10`000 of the "5 closest points" and only then narrows it down to 50 time steps I requested in the first place. It seems even more plausible since even .count() queries along the geo-index can take as much time.

So basically, if possible I would like to do it other way around: first narrow down some time steps, and only then perform the $near find or $geoNear aggregation on this considerably smaller dataset. It would help also that queries without geospatial part had kept their performance.

Hinting the other index in the .find() query breaks geospatial search and $geoNear accepts no aggregation pipeline steps before it. Ensuring geo-index before query for some reason created second geo-index, so aggregation became impossible

Two-step search or aggregation would have been great, but it seems that there is no such thing in mongo, and although I think it can be imitated with aggregating data into the proxy collection, it look like quite a bad idea.

It is possible though that I have some gradual misunderstanding about mongodb index work and/or lifetime, since request time is not consistently bad like it should have probably been if what I have just written was correct.

Just in case:

- mongodb 3.0.4;
- Motor 0.4.1 with pymongo 2.8, although problem was first discovered on pymongo 3.0.3;
- discussed collection is a part of replica set, querying script is running locally on the machine with secondary node.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: The [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour), doesn't hurt, either ;)